# Loop through a complex list using linq in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a field called *LotNo* and a List(Of LotDTO) called *LotsList* that has among other properties a LotNumber() property both of type string.

This if statement is not working `If (LotsList.Contains(selectedLot.LotNo) Then …` because I am obviously comparing a complex object to a string so what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
If LotsList.Any(Function(lot) lot.LotNo = selectedLot.LotNo) Then
```

The `Any` extension method will tell whether any items in a list satisfy an arbitrary Boolean condition.